# Function to count number of li elements in different divs, combining the count when there are divs with the same custom value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of filter checkboxes that are written in via JavaScript. The filter checkboxes come from divs with values that could be repeated.

```
<div value="a" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="b" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="c" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="c" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
```

I have an array of those different div values. (I cut to the chase here and am just showing the result of the array rather than how I created it.)

```
var allDivs = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f"]
```

I have a filtered version of the array so there are no duplicates. I use this array to generate a set of filter checkboxes.

```
var filteredDivs = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

What I'd like to do:
Each div contains a number of list items within it.

Next to each filter checkbox (from the filtered array with no duplicates), I'd like to provide a count of the li elements, combining the number of li elements from the duplicated entries.

So here's a representation of the number of li elements in each div.

- a = 4
- b = 5
- c = 2
- c = 7
- d = 5
- e = 2
- e = 3
- f = 6

...but combined (because I have two 'c' and 'e' divs), that would be:

- a = 5
- b = 5
- c = 9
- d = 5
- e = 5
- f = 6

I am able to get those individual counts by doing something like

```
$("a li").length
$("b li").length
$("c li").length
```

but I am having trouble turning that into a function.

For a bit more context...the filter checkboxes are written in like this, just to give you an idea.

```
var renderFilters = function (filteredDivs) {
    app.querySelector("#filters").innerHTML =
        filteredDivs.map(function (module, index) {
            var html =
                '<label class="filter">' +
                '<input type="checkbox" data-filter="' + filteredDivs[index] + '" checked>' +
                module + " (" + ")" // Would like the count of li items here.
            '</label>';
            return html;
        }).join('')
};
```

In addition to writing in the list of unique div values as filter checkboxes, I'd also like to display the count of the li items in the parentheses, combining them where appropriate.

I don't know where to start on this problem. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so that I can research an answer, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('[value]')
var values = Array.from(divs).map(d => d.getAttribute('value'));
var unique_values = Array.from(new Set(values));
var counts = unique_values.map(c => ({value: c, count: document.querySelectorAll('[value="' + c + '"] li').length}))
console.log(counts);
```

```html
<div value="a" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="b" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="c" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
<div value="c" class="foo">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</div>
```